# Vue js Bind dynamic id when adding text box dynamically on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am able to add textbox dynamically on button click. My problem is i cant set dynamic id and value.

```
<div id="app">
        <div>
            <button class="button btn-primary" @click="addRow">Add row</button>
        </div>
        <div v-for="row in rows">
            <button-counter></button-counter>
        </div>
    </div>       
    <script>    
        Vue.component('button-counter', {
            template: '<input type="text" style="margin-top: 10px;" ><br>'
        })    
        var app = new Vue({
            el: "#app",
            data: {
                rows: [],
                count:0              
            },
            methods: {
                addRow: function () {
                    var txtCount=++this.count;
                    id='txt_'+txtCount;
                    this.rows.push({ title: "first", description: "textbox1" });
                }
            }
        });

    </script> 


  This is my code.
```

I have created on component for input and created one vue instance.while clicking add row button, it will add a new textbox.but i dont know to bind id and value for textbox.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the id in the rows array

```
<div v-for="row in rows" :id=row.id>
  <button-counter></button-counter>
</div>
```

And pass the id while adding the new row

```
this.rows.push({ title: "first", description: "textbox1", id });
```

Comment: it would throw a warning:
`Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders.`

Answer (score 2):

You can add an `id` in your `rows` item and use that as an id. But I'm assuming you're doing this so you can retrieve the input value later on. There is a better way to do this.

Define a `values` object on your parent data object. Like this:

```
data: {
  rows: [],
  values: {},
  count:0              
},
```

Every time you add a new row add a reactive property to it:

```
addRow: function () {
  var txtCount=++this.count;
  id='txt_'+txtCount;
  this.rows.push({ title: "first", description: "textbox1"});
  this.$set(this.values, id, '')
},
```

Define a `value` prop on your custom component and emit an `input` event each time the value changes. Making your custom component ready to receive an `v-model`

```
Vue.component('button-counter', {
 props: ['value'],
 template: '<input type="text" @input="$emit(\'input\', 
  arguments[0].srcElement.value)" style="margin-top: 10px;" ><br>'
})
```

Bind each custom component to the correct `v-model`

```
<button-counter v-model='values[row.id]'></button-counter>
```

Now you have access to all the input values in `values` in the parent component.

Here's a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkf8pj0w/6/).

BTW: you're getting an error because your custom component has multiple roots. You need to either remove the `br` or add a wrapping element.

Answer (score 1):

Well, At first in order to identify every input element, you need to add `:key`  attr to `v-for`

and to bind value you can pass value and id as a prop while creating the input element and pass the value to the v-model of the input type so whenever it is created, you can have it inside the input.

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/doz04yru/)

Hope this helps!